# SQL difference of two rows

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have a table, **Table1**

```
Table1
ID  REG  VALUE
1   54   500
2   54   1700
3   60   5000
4   60   5500
```

Now, i need to copy rows from this table to a second one, **Table2**, but for entries with the same `REG` i want to make single row in the second table,with the difference between the highest `VALUE` and the lower `VALUE`, something like this:

```
Table2
ID  REG  VALUE
1   54   1200
2   60   500
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Oracle/MySQL/SQL Server?

Comment: none of the above, it's MS-Acces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an insert-select statement:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (reg, value)
SELECT   reg, MAX(value) - MIN(value)
FROM     table1
GROUP BY reg
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

EDIT:

If the requirement is to also copy values that appear on a single `reg` row too, this can be done using a `case` expression:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (reg, value)
SELECT   reg, 
         CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(value) ELSE MAX(value) - MIN(value) END
FROM     table1
GROUP BY reg
```

Comment: what if there is a lone row without a duplicate `REG` anywhere , would that return some faulty data possibly?

Comment: @Coffee..in that case the difference would be `0` as `max` and `min` are the same. and this will only insert rows when there are atleast 2 rows per `reg`. So, that shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: What if there is `NULL` in column like : `(5 ,  70  , 5500) and (6 ,  70  , NULL)`?

Comment: @vkp - OP said `need to copy rows from this table to a second one, Table2, but for entries with the same REG i want to make single row in the second table`  - so I'm not sure if OP thought through what he/she wants

Comment: @Coffee I implicitly assumed you'd only want to copy rows with more than one value. For a statement that copies a single row too, see my edited answer.

Comment: @lad2025 From OP's data it seems as though `null`s are not an issue. If this isn't true, you'll need to tweak the `having` clause. `min` and `max` just ignore `null`s, so that should be ok on that part.

Comment: @lad2025 replace the `count(*)` statements with `count(value)` if you want to handle `null`s.

Comment: @Coffee if a `reg` shows only once, that entry is not relevant for my querry. there are no `null` values on the `value` field, in worst case scenario, there would be a `0`.

Comment: @Mureinik Thank you very much, your `insert-select` statement is exactly what i need, and it works. Also, the `case` edit is a good learning example.